# Why does this code compile

Tags: c++, eigen

I don't understand why this code compiles and run without error :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 3/*FIXME: Should be 5*/> Matrix5;

  Matrix5 test;
  test << 2,0,0,1,1, 
          0,2,0,1,1,
          0,0,2,2,2,
          0,1,2,0,0,
          0,1,1,0,0; // We filled a 5*5 matrix in a 5*3 matrix

  //std::cout << "Test matrix:\n" << test << std::endl;
  return (0);
}
```

This is how I compiled the code:

```
g++ test_eigen.cpp -o test_eigen -I/usr/include/eigen3 -O3 -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG
```

Uncomment the `std::cout`, compile, run again and you will get a segmentation fault.
I'm using Eigen 3.2.0-8 on Ubuntu 14.04.

As suggested; here is the output of Valgrind (with `std::cout` commented) :

```
$ valgrind ./test_eigen
==12380== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12380== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12380== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12380== Command: ./test_eigen
==12380== 
==12380== 
==12380== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12380==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12380==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==12380== 
==12380== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12380== 
==12380== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12380== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Did you keep `cout` commented out when running valgrind? Chances are, compiler optimized out the code that misbehaves.

Comment: I suspect the massive use of expression templates and overloaded operators in Eigen are what made valgrind not see that this code writes past the end of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you compiled with assertions disabled.

Eigen overloads `operator<<` to enable matrices to be initialized with a comma separated list. (Note that this also means there's an override of the comma operator lurking behind the scenes). That comma separated list of items can contain numbers, but it can also contain a vector or another matrix.

This flexibility comes at a cost. Eigen cannot tell at compile time that the comma separated list contains too many or too few items. It instead detects too many / too few items at run time and complains via an `eigen_assert`. If you have compiled with assertions disabled, you have let that overly-full list of items change from a SIGABRT into undefined behavior.

This kind of thing happens all the time with undefined behavior, that adding a statement magically lets the code run without error. Don't take this as a sign that things are OK. It just happened to run. Undefined behavior is always bad. Just because it "works" in some cases doesn't mean that your code won't reformat your hard drive the next time you use the program.

Comment: Compiled with `g++ test_eigen.cpp -o test_eigen -I/usr/include/eigen3 -O3` and run; this is the output and assert error:

`Too many rows passed to comma initializer (operator<<)`

Disabling Eigen assertions was the root cause of why it ran without throwing an error.

Comment: With Eigen, you should only disable assertions after you have thoroughly tested your program to make sure everything work correctly.

Comment: And remember to re-enable the assertions every time you make changes... ;) [In practice, have a build setup that compiles with assertions and runs through a set of tests, along with building a version without asserts].

Comment: @MatsPetersson: isn't it the usual Debug vs Release dichotomy ? Or do you recommend a Release+Assert build as well (like Clang/LLVM) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Either/both. My point was that since projects are never quite completed (well, some are, some never finish), you end up making changes after the point where you have "thoroughly tested your program".

Answer (score 5):

Writing past the allocated bounds of a data structure (e.g. writing a 5x5 matrix into an allocated 5x3) is undefined behavior. It may or may not crash, and unfortunately may even run to completion without visible errors.

Run your code with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to pinpoint memory problems similar to the one you described.

Comment: The core dump is coming from `eigen_assert`. He should be seeing that regardless.

Comment: Correction: He won't necessarily see the assertion. He won't see the assertion if he compiled with assertions disabled, and then the extra items in the list becomes undefined behavior.

Comment: That is right; I forgot to mention I compiled with `-DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG`

Comment: I've submitted an answer that explains what's going on.

Comment: @DavidHammen Well, the source of the problem is in the code; the flag is just a way to hide it.

Comment: The problem is definitely in the code. The code will write past the end of the array if assertions are disabled. Note that I didn't downvote your answer. That overwriting invokes UB. The question asked is why wasn't there a compile time error. The answer is the flexibility of the overloaded comma operator precludes a compile time warning.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this code compile?

Because the compiler will not be able to know how many elements you passed to `operator<<` at compile time. That information is only available at runtime.

Comment: Except in this case it is known at compile time.

Comment: The `operator<<` is not the stream extraction operator in this case. The inputs are coming from that comma separated list (which takes advantage of overloading the comma operator).

Comment: @DavidHammen, never said it was. :)